# Bootstrap responsive navbar that becomes fixed after scroll a certain div

Tags: javascript, css, twitter-bootstrap, navbar, fixed

I'm trying to do something like this website http://www.rocketmill.co.uk/.
I need to fix the navbar when it reaches the top, but not giving any fixed height to the div above (orange in the case of the link) because it's responsive and the hight changes when the screen size reduces.

Comment: not sure if theres something in bootstrap specific to acheive this.  I use http://stickyjs.com/

Comment: Could you provide a js fiddle or example of code you've tried?

Comment: Please provide a jsfiddle showing what you have tried so far??

Comment: i just tried the sticky.js <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.sticky.js"></script>
   <script>
        $(window).load(function(){
          $("#myHeader").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
        });
      </script>

Comment: it seems to work on pcs but not on tablets and mobile

Answer (score 1):

Rather than writing new javascript for that, I would recommend you using Bootstrap `affix` instead.

You just need to add the proper attributes to your navbar like this:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" data-spy="affix" data-offset-top="200" role="navigation">
  --your navbar markup here--
</nav>
```

where `200` is the pixels from top.

Now just add this to your css:

```
.affix  {
  position: fixed;
  --other properties--
}
```

And the navbar should use the `.affix` properties on scroll.

Answer (score 0):

that's the code from sticky.js

```
  <script>
    $(window).load(function(){
      $("#myHeader").sticky({ topSpacing: 0 });
    });
  </script>
```